# Create a colormap that is assigned to specific integer values with numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, colormap

I am looking for  way to create a colormap in python/matplotlib that is specific to a designated integer value and remains that integer value. Here is an example of how I define the matlab colormap:

```
c_map = [1   1   1;...     % Integer assignment = 0 - Air - white
         0.6 1 0.8;... % Integer assignment = 1 - Water - cyan
         1 0.6 0.2];   % Integer assignment = 2 - Sediments - orange
```

it is later called during the plotting routine by:

```
colormap(c_map);
pcolor(xvec,zvec,ColorIntegers);
shading interp, colormap, caxis([0 3]), axis ij
```

The integer values always stay the same (i.e., Air = 0 , Water = 1, sediments = 2).

I've scoured the matplotlib documentation and stack, but haven't found a way to create this specific style colormap, which relates corresponding integers to a color. Most questions deal with diverging, jet, centering, linear, non-linear as opposed to a consistent coloring of specific colormaps. Each color ***must*** correspond to that ***specific*** integer value.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Would it be possible to set it up as a 0, 1, 2, ... map while plotting? `mapping.index(material)` or something like that. Not a nice hack, but still.

Comment: Hi Jean, thank you for your comment and really appreciate it. The answer below worked perfect. As I'm not a python guru - that seemed to be the most usable. Thanks again for you comment.

Comment: It's okay. I'd thought that `y` was `array([["water", "water", "sediment", ...]])`, and you wanted to convert it to integers. `mapping` could be a list (`["air", "water", "sediment", "rock"]`), or a dict (`{"air": 0, "water": 1, "sediment": 2, "rock": 3}`). Using `mapping.index(material)` for a list, or `mapping[material]` for a dict, would allow you to automatically convert it to numbers for drawing.

Comment: No worries! That is great to know about using lists. I have a lot to learn apparently. I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [`ListedColormap`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap).

For example,

```
In [103]: y
Out[103]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])

In [104]: c_map = [[1, 1, 1], [0.6, 1, 0.8], [1, 0.6, 0.2], [0.75, 0.25, 0.25]]

In [105]: cm = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(c_map)

In [106]: imshow(y, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm)
```

generates

[image]